# Нейронные сети на Python

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Кто сталкивался? Какие библиотеки посоветуете? Есть ли примеры работы у кого-нибудь?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Рекомендую [PyBrain](http://www.pybrain.org/pages/features): разные типы нейронных сетей (включая экзотические, вроде LSTM) и разные алгоритмы обучения этих сетей. Все это на Питоне. Можно смотреть исходники, а можно читать документацию.